# Filtering my an object

Tags: javascript

This code works for filtering my one Id.

```
let symbols =([
  {symbols:"XFX", id:1},
  {symbols:"XFF", id:2},
  {symbols:"XEE", id:20},
])

function getStocksOver(stocks, id){
  return stocks.filter(function(stock,index){
    return stock.id !=id;
  });
}

console.log(getStocksOver(symbols,1))
```

Now i would like to be able to filter by an object

```
 let symbolsDeleted =([
  {symbols:"XFX", id:1},
  {symbols:"XFF", id:2},
])
```

Does anyone know a way of doing this cause i really stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use map and filters

```
const symbolsDeleted =([
  {symbols:"XFX", id:1},
  {symbols:"XFF", id:2},
])

let symbols =([
  {symbols:"XFX", id:1},
  {symbols:"XFF", id:2},
  {symbols:"XEE", id:20},
])

function getStocksOver(stocks, oObject) {
  const keys = oObject.map(o => o.id);
  return stocks.filter((s) => !keys.includes(s.id));
}

console.log(getStocksOver(symbols, symbolsDeleted));
```

Comment: i am trying to update the symbols object by removing the symbolsdelete objects from it so i the include will not work for that

Comment: sorry, my mistake, you can do !keys.includes(s.id)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of comparing every stock.id to a single id, you can create an additional filter that filters your `symbolsDeleted` array by the stock id.

The length of the filter result will be 0 if there are no matches.

In that case you return true to the outer filter function.

If a match is found, false is returned.

```
let symbolsDeleted =([
  {symbols:"XFX", id:1},
  {symbols:"XFF", id:2},
])

let symbols =([
  {symbols:"XFX", id:1},
  {symbols:"XFF", id:2},
  {symbols:"XEE", id:20},
])

function getStocksOver(stocks, objArray){
  return stocks.filter(function(stock, index) {
    return objArray.filter(function(value) {
      return value.id == stock.id
    }).length == 0;
  });
}

console.log(getStocksOver(symbols, symbolsDeleted))
```